# Using Objective-C Introspection vs. Forcing Additional Message Override?

Tags: objective-c, introspection

I have a base class which adds some functionality to a number of derived classes in my app.

One of these features is only used by *some* subclasses.

Currently I'm using a method which returns a `BOOL` which defaults to `NO` to "short-circuit" this feature. Subclasses which want the feature must override this method and return `YES`.

This feature is only useful if you've also overridden at least one of two other methods.

I'd prefer to use `class_copyMethodList` to determine if the subclass implemented either of these two methods (instead of using the method which returns a `BOOL`).

What barriers/roadblocks/cons to this approach should I be aware of? Is there a standard implementation of this idiom which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may suggest an alternative approach, have you considered using `-instanceMethodForSelector` on the relevant subclass instance and comparing to the result on the base class?

That method returns an `IMP`, which is a  C function pointer to the implementation for the given selector. So if the subclass has a different implementation from the base class, it'll return a different `IMP`.

EDIT: as discussed in the comments below, a further alternative is to declare a formal protocol that the sub classes may implement, and to use `NSObject`'s `-conformsToProtocol:` to determine whether the protocol is implemented. Since `conformsToProtocol` returns whether the class has declared support for the protocol (in its `@interface` via the angle brackets syntax), that's a lot like adding a custom `BOOL` method that defaults to returning `NO` but without the syntactic and semantic overhead of adopting your own ad hoc solution.

Comment: Ah, ok... so basically: `[[self class] instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(...)] != [[BaseClass class] instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(...)]` ?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. As IMPs are actual pointers to real memory locations you should be fine to compare by value as a C primitive.

Comment: I'm still curious in a broader sense... (since your comment is mostly just a twist on the implementation of the approach)... is this a reasonable approach or would an informal protocol via `resondsToSelector` be more appropriate?

Comment: It doesn't actually need to be an informal protocol; you can add `@optional` methods to a formal protocol. The only problem I can see, if I've understood the question, is that the subclass instances will answer that they respond to the selector, because they've inherited that from the base.

Comment: Right. But I could use `conformsToProtocol` to check and see if the protocol is implemented... and, actually, this seems like the "right" way to go in my case. It seems more true to the language. Maybe, could you edit your answer to include this option?

Comment: The formal protocol with `conformsToProtocol:` seems appropriate. Then the superclass does not need to (and should not) implement stubs at all.

Comment: There are instances where stubs are appropriate — such as in more complicated hierarchies where you expect to subclass something a distance down the tree but are going to be thinking in terms of the root class. `layoutSubviews` on `UIView` is an example. Anyway, I've added some stuff on `conformsToProtocol` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a base class which adds some functionality to a number of derived classes in my app.

This sentence should cause you to rethink your design. A base class should never do anything to derived classes. It should be ignorant of its subclasses. (Class Clusters notwithstanding. That's a separate design approach and require the superclass to be aware in the construction, making it the Factory pattern, which is fine.)

> One of these features is only used by some subclasses.

This is a strong indication of a "Square/Rectangle" mistake. In OOP (forget ObjC, this is just CS theory), a [square is not a rectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem). You need to ensure that your types conform to Liskov's Substitution Principle. Again, this has nothing to do with any particular language; it's true of all OOP design. It may seem very "theoretical" but it will seriously screw up your implementation if you fail LSP, and you will chase subtle bugs for much longer than you like.

The pattern you probably want here is Decorator rather than subclassing. If you have some special functionality that exists on some classes, you want to encapsulate that functionality into a separate object and attach it to subclasses where it makes sense. Another possible pattern is Strategy (which is generally implemented as a "delegate" in ObjC, which is another way of thinking about Decorator). The point is that you don't want logic in the superclass that is only applicable to some subclasses. You want to put that logic into something that only exists in the appropriate subclasses.

If all of those things fail you, then I strongly recommend a simple `(BOOL)` function over anything that introspects the method implementations. That way is fragile because it relies on ever-deeper implementation details. `respondsToSelector:` is definitely better than testing `instanceMethodForSelector:`.

Comment: Hrm... You may be reading too much into my question (I was trying to be succinct). I take your point about creating another tier of classes by subclassing my base class, adding in the functionality I want in some of my subclasses there, and using this new class as the base class for my subclasses. However, I think to (without more context than you have) take the single sentence I wrote about functionality and claim that I have a broken design may be a bit over the top. "Adds Functionality" may not have been a great choice of words. "Makes some functionality accessible in a consistent way".

Comment: PS.) Imagine for a minute you're Microsoft and you're building a new version of ASP.NET... millions of sites use `System.Web.Page` (or whatever it is I forget) as their base class for each and every page. You want to roll out a new version of the framework with new features. One could argue (to your point) that the "correct" way to do it would be to create a `System.Web.Page2` class (based on `System.Web.Page`) with the new functionality. There are, however, serious drawbacks to that approach in terms of training and retrofitting.

Comment: Apple and `UIViewController` is a suitable example as well. My two options according to you are; A.) Create `UIViewControllerVersion2` with the new features and force everyone to move to that if they want to use the new features, or B.) Rename `UIViewController` --> `UIViewControllerBase` and create a new `UIViewController` based on `UIViewControllerBase` with the extra (expensive) operations I need (and force everyone who doesn't need the expensive operations to change their base class to `UIViewControllerBase`.

Comment: I hope you read all those comments as *probing* rather than as *argumentative*. I'm anxious to hear your thoughts given my additional remarks.

Comment: There are several other options than the ones you note. A key one is to create a helper class that contains the additional functionality (a Decorator) and attach it to classes that request it. OS X did this with `CALayer` and the `wantsLayer` property on `NSView`. Typically the request is made by the subclass overriding a YES/NO boolean or setting a property, not by introspecting the subclass. This is your current implementation and is a common solution. What's wrong with it? ObjC-level introspection seems a complex solution that hides too much from the caller.

Comment: Note that in 64-bit Mac and all iOS versions of ObjC, there is no fragile base-class problem. You can swap out a superclass implementation and retain binary compatibility. I'm not clear on your example of adding functionality to `UIViewController`. Apple does that every release without requiring subclass introspection.

Comment: The introspection is very short (4 lines, really)... the YES/NO override is just seemingly pointless... as an inheritor I just want to override the methods I'm interested in... the YES/NO seems very much "out of the way". I think @Tommy and I found a better solution; create a protocol and in the base class i can check `conformsToProtocol` and, if so, enable the feature. How do you feel about that?

Comment: `conformsToProtocol` is a good solution. It was one of the ways I originally wrote up in one of my drafts. The problem isn't the number of lines. It's the fragility. Introspecting method implementations in code you don't control ties you too much to a low-level implementation detail. It's powerful (KVO uses it), but it's a last resort "I really need this" approach. `conformsToProtocol:` is a much more common way for classes to talk to each other.